# Using macro parameter # after control sequence character \

Tags: macros

I'm making a new command like which goes kind of like this:

```
\newcommand\mycommand[1]{\#1section}
```

So, what I what is to type `\mycommand{sub}{blah}` to output `\subsection{blah}` and `\mycommand{subsub}{blah}` to output `\subsubsection{blah}`. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\csname` allows to construct command sequence names:

```
\newcommand*{\mycommand}[1]{\csname#1section\endcsname}
```

If the constructed command is not defined, then it does not throw an error. Instead, the constructed command has the meaning `\relax`.

Comment: Nice, so `\csname` allows you to construct command sequence names, but is there anything that allows you to construct  variables defined with `\def`?

Comment: @SkeletonBow The "command sequence names" are just command tokens that start with the escape char (backslash). Macros (defined by `\def`, `\newcommand`, ...) belong to them.

Comment: Oh, okay. Then my problem must lie elsewhere. I just checked and confirmed what you said, anyway :) )

Comment: @SkeletonBow Probably, a missing `\expandafter`: `\expandafter\def\csname ...\endcsname`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it didn't work. If you want to, you can see a MWE of my problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378202/csname-endcsname-not-working-with-newfontfamily). If you don't, have a nice day!

Comment: @SkeletonBow -- to make this question "persistent", please insert your mwe in the question itself, not linked elsewhere.  (even though it links to another tex.sx question, which probably won't disappear, this one will be more helpful to future visitors if it is complete.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. The question I linked showcases *another* problem I was having (it's not related to my "question" in this question). If I'm mistaken, please let me know.