# \csname ... \endcsname not working with \newfontfamily

Tags: macros

I have an MWE below showing my problem (I got the general document outline from [this answer:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223340/116990)

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newfontfamily\cyrillicfontsf{CMU Sans Serif}[Script=Cyrillic]

% What I'm trying to replace
% \newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{CMU Serif}[Script=Cyrillic]

% What I'm trying to replace it with
\newcommand\mycommand[2]{\newfontfamily\csname#1font\endcsname{#2}[Script=Cyrillic]}
\mycommand{cyrillic}{CMU Serif}

\setmainlanguage{ukrainian}

\begin{document}
\author{А.В. Тор}
\title{Великий об'єм }
\maketitle
\section{Перший}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

So the problem here is that I feel as though what I'm trying to replace and what I'm trying to replace it by are equivalent. However, I am thrown the following error:

```
fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "c" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

So it seems to be taking just the first letter of the argument `cyrillic`, but that seems strange as I'm putting it in the `\csname ... \endcsname` environment. How should I go about fixing this?

I also tried `\expandafter` before the `\newcommand`, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: I'm really dubious about the usefulness of such a command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> \newcommand\mycommand[2]{\newfontfamily\csname#1font\endcsname{#2}[Script=Cyrillic]}
> ```

`\newfontfamily` does not see a command sequence, but `\csname` as first argument.
`\expandafter` helps by creating the command sequence *before* `\newfontfamily` parses its arguments:

```
\newcommand\mycommand[2]{\expandafter\newfontfamily\csname#1font\endcsname{#2}[Script=Cyrillic]}
```